# Parse.Query sort by date

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Is there a way to sort by `createdAt` time in parse?

For example:

```
var Users = Parse.Object.extend("Users"),
    Query = Parse.Query;

var userQuery = new Query(Users);

userQuery.equalTo("userName", Name);

userQuery.ascending("createdAt");
```

Comment: Yes, that is fine... but the string name of the Users class is not Users, it's "_Users".. better still: new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that is fine... but the string name of the Users class is not Users, it's "_Users".. better still: new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.ascending("createdAt");
```

But... Your user class should *not* be user queryable.  This should be locked down in the class-level permissions section of the data browser, and only Cloud Code using the Master Key should be able to query users.